# Cannot capture debug logs for Duplicate Management trigger

Tags: trigger, duplicate-management

Does anyone know how to capture debug logs for trigger execution on the new Duplicate Management object DuplicateRecordItem? I've set debug logs for myself, and the execution of the DuplicateRecordItem trigger doesn't show up. I know the trigger executes because I tested writing a record from it. The duplicate item records are created with 'Automated Process' as the created by user. I haven't been able to put a debug log on that user because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: I have not. I was temporarily writing statements to a custom object for debugging. Eventually, I moved most of the logic to the lead trigger where I had more control/visibility into processing, and left only minimal logic in the DuplicateRecordItem trigger to minimize the challenge of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

@Dave Helgerson You probably don't care about this anymore, but for everyone else who searches for this issue:

The Automated Process "user" doesn't exist, but you can still track the debug logs.

1. Navigate to Setup -> Debug Logs
2. Click "New"
3. For "Traced Entity Type", choose "Automated Process" (Do NOT try to search for the user - it's a "user" but not a user at the same time, apparently. Thanks, Salesforce!)